# What are the thoughts?

Tags: neuroscience, brain, neurology, thought

At the neuroscience level, what are thoughts? I mean, are they just electrical synapse through the brain in a recognizable patterns? if so, How are those electrical pulses originated?

Comment: Related: [How exactly do “you” think and interact with your body?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/12493/21)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How does subjective experience arise from matter?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/8056/21)

Comment: Most likely the best duplicate: [What are current neuronal explanations and models of 'consciousness'?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/987/21)